# Check if every value of a column contains integer, if not print the index of that cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

Suppose I have a column with mixture of integer and float, I need to run a loop through that column to check if all values are numeric. Values that aren't numeric, dump the index of that cell in a blank list.

A column like this:

```
DESCRIPTION                      RATE
79th St & Private Dr - 5022 W        1.5
79th St & Allison Ave                1.5
Allison Ave & 81st St                1
81st St & Norfolk St                 1
Norfolk St & Private Dr - 8178 N     1
Norfolk St & 84th St                 1
Moller Rd & 86th St                  1.5
Zionsville Rd & 86th St              1.5
```

I wrote a code like this but the newlist loop isn't working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Python34\\python scripts\\BNSF\\data\\data.csv") #read csv
col=df.columns #read header
print(col)
r=df.shape[0] #gives number of row count
c=df.shape[1] #gives number of col count
print(r, c)
typ=df.dtypes
print(typ)

newlist=[] #creates blank list
for i in range(r,1):
    if df.iloc[i,1].dtype == np.int64:
        pass
    else:
        print(df.iloc[i,1])
        newlist.append(df.iloc[i,1])
        print(newlist)
```

Need changes inside that loop. Please help.

Comment: What indices do you want in `newlist`, the row, the column or something like a tuple `(row, column)`? Note that right now you are are appending _values_ of the data frame, not indices. In any case, in Pandas dtypes are determined per column, so probably you don't need to traverse every cell...

Comment: What will be newlist from your data?

Comment: newlist = [[row,column], [row,column]]

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of pandas is that you can often avoid using loops. Sorting the data into integers/non-integers may be achieved by doing the modulo 1 operation and checking zero equivalence `%1==0` producing a DataFrame of True/False values in the variable `intcheck`. Then just get the `True` rows which are the integers from the original DataFrame. Placing a `~` in front inverts the boolean to get the non-integer values.

```
import pandas as pd

d =[["79th St & Private Dr - 5022 W"        ,1.5],
    ["79th St & Allison Ave"                ,1.5],
    ["Allison Ave & 81st St"                ,1  ],
    ["81st St & Norfolk St"                 ,1  ],
    ["Norfolk St & Private Dr - 8178 N"     ,1  ],
    ["Norfolk St & 84th St"                 ,1  ],
    ["Moller Rd & 86th St"                  ,1.5],
    ["Zionsville Rd & 86th St"              ,1.5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['DESCRIPTION','RATE'])
df = df.set_index('DESCRIPTION')

intcheck = (df.RATE%1)==0

print(df[intcheck])

#                                   RATE
# DESCRIPTION                           
# Allison Ave & 81st St              1.0
# 81st St & Norfolk St               1.0
# Norfolk St & Private Dr - 8178 N   1.0
# Norfolk St & 84th St               1.0

print(df[~intcheck])

#                                RATE
# DESCRIPTION                        
# 79th St & Private Dr - 5022 W   1.5
# 79th St & Allison Ave           1.5
# Moller Rd & 86th St             1.5
# Zionsville Rd & 86th St         1.5
```